# Unexpected behaviour in bash redirection

Tags: bash

I found a strange and totally unexpected behaviour while working with redirection in bash and even If I manage to work around it, I'd like to know why it happens.

If I run this command:`{ echo wtf > /dev/stdout ; } >> wtf.txt` N times, I expect to see the filled with N "wtf" lines. What I found in the file is a single line.

I think that since the first command is opening /dev/stdout in truncate mode, then the mode is inherited by the second file descriptor (wtf.txt), which is then completely erased, but I'd like to know if some of you may explain it better and if this is the correct behaviour or a bug.

Just to be clear, the command I used was a different one, but with the *echo* example is simpler to understand it. The original command was a command who need an output file as argument and since I want the output on stdout I passed */dev/stdout* as argument. The same behaviour may be verified with the command `openssl rand -hex 4 -out /dev/stdout >> wtf.txt`.

Finally, the solution I managed to fix the problem delegating the append operation to *tee* in the following way: `{ echo wtf > /dev/stdout } | tee -a wtf.txt > /dev/null`

Comment: That's because the redirection `>> wtf.txt` happens first, and then, when  `> /dev/stdout` is processed, you're not appending anymore to stdout because of the `>` instead of a `>>`. So, it works: `{ echo wtf >> /dev/stdout ; } >> wtf.txt`

Comment: Think that you're doing something like : `echo wtf >> wtf.txt > wtf.txt`. With `>> wtf.txt` you have `/dev/stdout` *pointing* to `wtf.txt`. Then, with `> /dev/stdout` you're replacing the previous redirection. `/dev/stdout`, at this point, is a symlink to `wtf.txt`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in either bash 3.2 or bash 4.3, either by running each of the N commands manually or rapidly within a loop.

Comment: Hm. Does your file system have an entry for `/dev/stdout`? `bash` handles `/dev/stdout` differently if it isn't an actual file; I wonder if the behavior is different in that case.

Comment: I have this problem on bash 4.2.25 (Ubuntu 12.04) and on bash 4.3.42 (Arch Linux). The output of 'ls /dev/stdout -l' is 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Nov  6 09:26 /dev/stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1' on both systems.

Comment: @chepner, I have a `/dev/stdout` file in my system and I can reproduce it.

Comment: I claim this depends on the file system and not just the shell. It works as expected on Mac OS X (`/dev/stdout` links to  `fd/1`, not an entry under `/proc`), and I can indeed reproduce the unexpected behavior on Linux in both `bash` and `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what happens using strace:

```
strace -o wtf-trace.txt -ff bash -c '{ (echo wtf) > /dev/stdout; } >> wtf.txt'
```

This will generate two files like `wtf-trace.txt.12889` and `wtf-trace.txt.12890` in my case. What happens is, process 1 `>> wtf.txt`:

```
open("wtf.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
clone(child_stack=0, .................) = 12890
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) .............) = 12890
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

The first process opens or creates "wtf.txt" for appending and get FD 3. After that it duplicates FD 1 with FD 3 and closes FD 3. At this point it forks (clone), waits for it to exit and exits itself.

The second process `{ echo wtf > /dev/stdout }` inherits the file by FD 1 (stdout) and it does:

```
open("/dev/stdout", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
write(1, "wtf\n", 4)                    = 4
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

As you can see it opens `/dev/stdout` (note `O_TRUNC`) and gets FD 3, dup2 to get FD 3 to FD 1, closes FD 3, checks FD 1 and gets a file with size of 0 `st_size=0`, writes to it and exits.

If you do `| cat >>` then the second process gets it FD 1 connected to a pipe, which is not seek-able or truncate-able...

NB: I show only the relevant lines of the files strace generated.